# Python Unrecognized time format

Tags: python, datetime, time

What time format is this `2014-06-14T16:46:01.000Z` ?

How can I `strftime` that into human readable form? I don't recognized what the `T` and `Z` mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: That is a UTC timestamp in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) Extended format - also described by [RFC 3339](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339).

Comment: Answers and thanks shouldn't be a part of the question, so I rolled back.

Comment: @OlehPrypin Sorry didn't know that is disallowed. I just posted my solution after reading this ISO time format in case it could be helpful to others reading from the future.

Answer (score 3):

To convert this don't use `strftime` use `date.util`

```
import dateutil.parser
nowdate = dateutil.parser.parse(datestring)
```

you can also use https://bitbucket.org/micktwomey/pyiso8601

```
>>> import iso8601
>>> iso8601.parse_date("2007-01-25T12:00:00Z")
datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 25, 12, 0, tzinfo=<iso8601.Utc>)
>>>
```

Comment: I think you meant `don't` not `dont#t`

Answer (score 2):

It is a combined date and time representation according to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 2):

You can't run an `strftime` as it can be applied only on date objects. But you can convert this string to a dateobject using strftime

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime("2014-06-14T16:46:01.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print date
```

**output**

```
2014-06-14 16:46:01
```

**T** and **Z** are designatiors for time and zone